# Show there exists a strictly increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a bounded above non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$. Let $u:=sup A \in \Bbb R \backslash A$, show that there exists a strictly increasing sequence $(a_n)$ in A s.t. $\lim\limits_{n}a_n=u$

Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence in A. For any $\epsilon$, there exists $x_{n_0}$ s.t. $u- \epsilon<x_{n_0}$, i.e. $|x_{n_0}-u|<\epsilon$. Take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{k}$, then we have a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$of $(x_n)$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n}x_{n_k}=u$. But how can I construct a strictly increasing sequence?

Comment: Why should this be true for **any** sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$? Say for example $A = [0,1)$ and $u = 1$. If I choose the sequence $x_n = 0$ for all $n$, then surely it does not have any subsequence whose limit is $u$.

Comment: @Bungo So if I choose a particular sequence $(x_n)$ s.t. $u-x_k<\frac{1}{k}$, would it be possible? If yes, then I think have constructed the required sequence?

Comment: Certainly you can choose a sequence such that $u - x_k < 1/k$. This will converge to $u$, but in general such a sequence need not be strictly increasing. But what happens if you modify the construction so that first we choose $x_1$ such that $u - x_1 < 1$, then choose $x_2$ such that $u - x_2 < \min(1/2, u - x_1)$, and in general, choose $x_k$ such that $u - x_k < \min(1/k, u - x_{k-1})$. Do you see why this works, and in particular do you see how we are implicitly using the fact that $u \not\in A$?

Comment: The reason to add the $min(1/k,u-x_{k-1}$ is to make sure the next term we choose is bigger than the preceding term. You use the fact that $u \notin A$ is to make sure the term $x_k$ we pick won't be exactly equal to $u$, otherwise we cannot pick a strictly increasing sequence (we will end up picking $x_k=u$ for $k>N$). Hope I'm right. Also, thank you for replying.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since $u=\sup A\not \in A,$ for every $r>0$ there exists $a\in A$ with $a\in (u-r,u).$ So take any $x_1\in A$ and inductively choose $x_{n+1}\in A$ such that  $$x_{n+1}\in (u-r_n,u)$$ $$\text { where }\quad r_n=\frac {1}{2}(u-x_n).$$ As $r_n>0,$ we have $ x_{n+1}>u-r_n>u-2r_n=u_n.$

By induction on $n>0$ we have $0<u-x_{n+1}<2^{-n}(u-x_1)$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=u.$